# I want to sort by random

Tags: php, sql

This is my line of code that shown products from database, but I want to show it randomly every time.

Code:

```
$products = DB::select("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY category = 75 DESC LIMIT 4");
```

Comment: `category = 75` looks like it should be in a `where` clause.

Comment: I'm, not programmer can you give me the full line of code?

Comment: There are many threads on this topic already, have you looked at them already and they didn't resolve the issue?

Comment: Are you wanting to select 4 random products with category 75?

Comment: Based on your comments I don't think the question has a full description of what you want. Please update, the `category = 75` is misleading, if you really want random categories.

Answer (score 1):

Why you ordering by category = 75? You meant `where category = 75`?

You can use `ORDER BY RAND()`:

```
$products = DB::select("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4");
```

but you may expect some performance issues.

Comment: Yeah, but i want to show random from a database category.

Comment: 75 is the category id.

Comment: @gucciboss Please define exactly what you want in the question. 4 random and different categories everytime?

Comment: So better way is select all categories from db, shuffle them in php and run your query with id from first row of shuffled array.

Comment: Thank you, i have completed that.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `RAND()` to order randomly;

```
$products = DB::select("SELECT * FROM products where category = 75 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4");
```

Comment: Thank you that is what i asked :)